# IntParse to TryParse

Tags: c#, try-catch, tryparse

I am trying to transform this piece of code:

```
try
{
    recordID = Int64.Parse(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(conn, CommandType.Text, sqlString, parms).ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    int x = 1;
}
```

into a TryParse code.
Do I need the catch (Exception)?

Comment: In my experience, if you have to ask, yes.  Be sure you handle that case properly though, or don't handle it at all.

Comment: TryParse will not throw, it returns false if the parse failed **but** there is a lot more going on in the try block than a parse ... E.g. all the DB work can also throw exceptions.  Currently any query or connection problems are completely ignored, which seems unwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TryParse method itself does not require catch clause.
But there is a lot of other calls in your code.
If you have int column type in your DB I recommend you to use the value directly:

```
try
{
    recordID = Convert.ToInt64(SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(conn, CommandType.Text, sqlString, parms));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   LogError(ex);
}
```

Because converting to string and then from string is additional work.